# how to resolve "UndeclaredThrowableException"

Tags: java, spring, testing, development-environment

I developed one consumer application and tested it on my system, everything is working fine and I provided EAR file to testing team.But when they try to access My application most of the functionalities are working fine, Some functionality they getting "UndeclaredThrowableException". Please find the below error stack trace.

**Error**:

> ```
> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>
>         at $Proxy2.setQuestionsAnsweredFailures(Unknown Source)
>
>         at DACTest.main(DACTest.java:59)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toyota.security.tbg2.dispatch.LDAPOperationException
>
>         at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtility.java:103)
>
>         at org.jboss.remoting.loading.RemotingClassLoader.loadClass(RemotingClassLoader.java:86)
>
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>
>         at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:179)
>
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
>
>         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
> ```

Please provide any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: is `com.toyota.security.tbg2.dispatch.LDAPOperationException` included in the EAR?

Comment: Is your application making remote EJB calls to another server?

Comment: @wero : we have LDAPOperationException class in our application EAR file